# Sampling interval $T$ as a multiplier in digital processing of a continuous-time signals

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, continuous-signals, analog-to-digital, digital-to-analog

[image]

[from: *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, Oppenheim and Schafer, p.224]

Q:  Why do we have $T$ as multiplier in $TY_a(j\Omega)$ in Eq.155?

Comment: Could be a typing error. The notation feels a bit sloppy: $y_a$ and $e_$ are not defined in the pictures so it's hard to determine what exactly $Y_a$ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a typo, but it has to do with the sampling process. As shown in Eq. $(4.30)$ in the 3rd edition of *Discrete-time Signal Processing* by Oppenheim and Schafer, (ideal) sampling involves scaling by $1/T$, where $T$ is the sampling period. If the continuous-time signal $x_c(t)$ is ideally band-limited, the spectrum of the discrete-time signal $x_d[n]=x_c(nT)$ after sampling is given by

$$X(e^{j\Omega T})=\frac{1}{T}X_c(j\Omega)\tag{1}$$

So if you divide both sides of Eq. $(155)$ by $T$ you see that on the right-hand side you get the scaled spectrum of the continuous-time signal, which equals the spectrum of the discrete-time signal.